# How to configure dual SSL WebSocket Servers using Node

Tags: node.js, ssl, websocket, server

I have an SSL enabled Node server (v0.10.35) that provides the user with HTTPS and WSS connections. I would like to add a new SSL enabled WebSocket server to this configuration to allow me to connect a control application to the Node server, ideally using a different URL. For example:

Public Access : https://myserver (via Browser)

Control Access : wss://myserver/control (via my Software)

I am assuming that this can be done but I'll be honest I do not have a clue as to how to configure it, so I would appreciate help from those that do.

I don't know if it is worth while pointing out but my current implementation already supports WS to the Browser, this allows me to (obviously) send and receive messages.

What I would like to do is either add another WS Server to handle the control messages or configure my existing install to have multiple URLs so the browser would default to wss://myserver but the application would use wss://myserver/control for example.

Comment: It would be good to specify what software you are using, like Express framework, to get any help.

Comment: Thanks for that micnic, I am only using Node and WebSockets require('ws').Server if that helps.

Comment: As I saw `ws` module does not offer such a thing out of the box, you'll have to listen for `upgrade` event and attach the `ws.Request()` to the incoming HTTP request and manipulate the connection. I would recommend you, for this task,  my module https://github.com/micnic/simpleS/ , it has built-in WebSocket support and can help you. You can create with it another server an listen for WSS connections on the specific path and some specific port like 8000. Its next version (0.7.0), will appear soon with a lot of improvements

Comment: micnic, that looks interesting do you have an example of how I could accomplish my goal? In the mean time I'll see if anyone else has anything to say.

Comment: As just a quick start with my module: `simples(8000/*, ssl may be defined here*/).ws('/control', function (connection) { /* do what you want */ })` , see the documentation for more information. With `ws` module will be more difficult, it depends on your server's structure.